# Setting height back to 0 after toggling a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML and JS.  When you click the `.slidedown-toggle` it toggles the class 'open' on it's parent (`.slidedown`) and applies the height to it's sibling (`.nav-sub`).  This is working, but what isn't working setting the height back to 0 when that 'open' class isn't present.  What am I missing?

**HTML**

```
<li class="slidedown">
  <a href="#">Parent Link</a>
  <!-- Dropdown arrow -->
  <span class="slidedown-toggle">
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </span>
  <!-- Submenu -->
  <ul class="nav nav-sub">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Child Menu Item 1</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

**JS**

```
$(function navCollapse(){

  var slidedownToggle = $( '#global-nav .slidedown-toggle' );

  slidedownToggle.click( function() {
    var slidedown = $(this).parent( '.slidedown' );
    var navOpen = $( '#global-nav li.open' );
    var subnav = $(this).siblings( '.nav-sub' );
    var subnavHeight = subnav.height();

    slidedown.toggleClass( 'open' );

    if (navOpen){
      subnav.height( subnavHeight );
    }else{
      subnav.height( 0 );
    }

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$( '#global-nav li.open' )` will return a jQuery object which will always be truthy, you need to check whether the `li` to which current toggle element belongs to has the class open.

You can use .closest() to find the `li` element and then use .hasClass() to check whether the class is present

```
$(function navCollapse() {

    var slidedownToggle = $('#global-nav .slidedown-toggle');

    slidedownToggle.click(function () {
        var slidedown = $(this).parent('.slidedown');
        var $li = $(this).closest('li');
        var subnav = $(this).siblings('.nav-sub');
        var subnavHeight = subnav.height();

        slidedown.toggleClass('open');

        if ($li.hasClass('open')) {
            subnav.height(0);
        } else {
            subnav.height(subnavHeight);
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks.  I've just realised that: a) If I set the height in CSS to 0 then this script will calculate the height to 0.  b) After the script has set the height to 0 on the second click, it will only calculate it as 0 from then on. Back to the drawing board maybe.

Answer (score 0):

***[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/oGuqocE/1/edit)***

```
  var $gNav = ('#global-nav');

  $('.slidedown-toggle', $gNav).click( function( e ) { 

    var myLI = $(this).closest('.slidedown');
    var isON = myLI.hasClass('open');

    // ALL
    $('li.open', $gNav).removeClass('open').find('.nav-sub').slideUp();

    // THIS
    myLI.toggleClass('open', !isON).find('.nav-sub').stop().slideToggle();  

  });
```

Comment: This isn't what the question asked?  I don't want any animation via JS, that's why I'm calculating the height.

Comment: @davidpauljunior the height of what? `subnav = $(this).siblings( '.nav-sub' );` all your `.subnav elements`? what for?

Comment: I want the height of the '.nav-sub' that is the sibling of the slidedown-toggle that's been clicked.  I want that so I can transition it with CSS.  My fallback is to use max-height but I don't want to guess the max-height of the longest list.

Comment: But I've just realised why that won't work because of calculating the height with JS and having it set to 0 in the CSS.  Back to square one.

Comment: @davidpauljunior the CSS was the only thing we missed in your question to maybe help you get to something. Probably it's never late for you to show us in an extended demo what you're up to

Comment: Thanks.  I'll have another think and come back once things are a bit clearer.  I marked the other answer correct as it did what I asked for, even though it turned out to not really help me.

Comment: I've re-added my question with a better description of what I'm trying to achieve.  If you are able to take a look it would be amazing, but of course there's no pressure. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21274905/jquery-set-height-on-a-sibling-when-clicked

Comment: @davidpauljunior again, you did not added a CSS sample /or/ a jsBin.com demo... I'll try to do my best. BTW you've could edit this question instead of creating a duplicate...