# jQuery set height on a sibling when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Earlier I asked [this question about setting a height back to 0 after toggling a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273063/setting-height-back-to-0-after-toggling-a-class/21273396?noredirect=1#comment32054937_21273396).

Whilst the answer was correct, it turned out my question was not so I'm back to rephrase and try and solve my problem.

- I have a navigation list and some items have a sub navigation list inside them
- Each item that has a sub navigation has a toggle arrow which you click
- I want the sub navigation `<ul>` to start with a height of 0, and when you click the toggle arrow I want to use jQuery to set that sub navigation's height to the calculated height of it's items

[image]

The HTML is like this:

```
<li class="slidedown">
  <a href="#">Parent Link</a>
  <!-- Dropdown arrow -->
  <span class="slidedown-toggle">
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </span>
  <!-- Submenu -->
  <ul class="nav nav-sub">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Child Menu Item 1</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

The answer to my previous question gave me this script:

```
$(function navCollapse() {

  var slidedownToggle = $('#global-nav .slidedown-toggle');

  slidedownToggle.click(function () {
    var slidedown = $(this).parent('.slidedown');
    var $li = $(this).closest('li');
    var subnav = $(this).siblings('.nav-sub');
    var subnavHeight = subnav.height();

    slidedown.toggleClass('open');

    if ($li.hasClass('open')) {
        subnav.height(0);
    } else {
        subnav.height(subnavHeight);
    }

  });

});
```

**BUT** I quickly realised that once the height had been set to 0, the script would continue to calculate it as 0 from then on, no matter how many times you click.
Which leaves me stuck and confused.

The old Bootstrap Collapse is pretty much what I want (only the height change).  It sets the height via JavaScript and then uses CSS to do the transition. Although I'd prefer not to have my sub-menu have `display: none`.

Any ideas?

NOTE:  I don't want to use JavaScript animations.  I want to use CSS for that.
I also don't want to use the `max-height` solution to CSS only dropdowns.  That is my fallback.

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ozaPaFoM/2/edit)**

Comment: can u create [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/)  ?

Comment: **Why to bother with height at all**? You can simply `.toggle()` your elements on click, no need to set any height.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - without JS transitions?

Comment: @davidpauljunior what transitions? `.toggle()` just toggles a `display:inline/block` and `display:none;` of an element.

Comment: WHy you want to do the animations in CSS? what's wrong with jQuery? jQuery will make your animations available also to non-HTML5 browsers

Comment: @davidpauljunior I think that here you're just having the classic issue that you started all in your mind with CSS animations, and than run into the common problem that you cannot use `transition` to *toggle* `display` on your inner `UL` elements, but you can just do it using `max-height`. So believe me do it purely in jQuery. (P.S. you can do it also all without a single line of JS, in pure CSS... it's just a bit tricky)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'm a bit lost on the `.toggle()` thing. Not sure how that would slide down.  jQuery transition was more jerky on some devices (and I thought CSS was faster too)  I'd rather use the `max-height` CSS slide down technique than go for the JS animation.  Because you can't transition to `height: auto` in CSS, I wanted to calculate the height with JS but then do the animation with CSS.

Comment: using jquery you can say onclick, if the dropdown does not have a class, add it and `slideDown()`.  if it has that new class, remove it and `slideUp()`.  You don't need to worry about setting a height at that point.

Comment: @ntgCleaner I know that, I didn't want to use JS animations/transitions.

Comment: @davidpauljunior I'm sorry about that, I got too excited.  If you're willing to usee javascript, why not use the animations?

Comment: @ntgCleaner he already said: he's concerned about performance (and rightly so in some cases)

Comment: @gnack he said nothing about performance, just it being "jerkey" and with so few elements moving, it wouldn't make a difference JS vs CSS@davidpauljunior, You can set your opacity on your element to 0 without `display:none`, then when the DOM loads, find the height with jquery.javascript (`var elemHeight = $('.element').height();`) then the next line would be something like `$('.element').height(0);`  After that, you can use CSS transitions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999749/performance-of-css-transitions-vs-js-animation-packages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems with the logic of your code, so I've made some modifications.

```
$(function navCollapse() {

    var slidedownToggle = $('#global-nav .slidedown-toggle');

    slidedownToggle.click(function () {
        // Get the container item
        var $slidedown = $(this).parents('.slidedown');

        // Get the ul that needs to slide up/down
        var $subnav = $(this).siblings('.nav-sub');

        // Calculate the height required (in px) to show all LIs
        var totalHeight = 0;
        $subnav.find('li').each(function() {
            totalHeight += $(this).height();
        });

        // Set the appropriate height
        if ($slidedown.hasClass('open')) {
            $subnav.css({height: '0px'});
        } else {
            $subnav.css({height: totalHeight + 'px'});
        }
        $slidedown.toggleClass('open');

    });

});
```

Then in your CSS make sure you apply the transition to your `.nav-sub`:

```
-webkit-transition: height 0.2s linear;
-moz-transition: height 0.2s linear;
-ms-transition: height 0.2s linear;
-o-transition: height 0.2s linear;
transition: height 0.2s linear;
```

Working example:

http://jsbin.com/INIwuTA/11/

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way: http://jsfiddle.net/Tes9P/2/

Basically, this applies the transition to a wrapper div that goes around the sub menu. Because CSS transitions require a set height to animate to (you can't animate to auto) this wrapper needs to have a height larger than what your largest sub-menu will have.

In my jsfiddle, I set up the CSS like this:

```
.nav-sub {
    height:auto;
    background-color:#eee;

}

.nav-sub-holder {
       -webkit-transition:  height 2s ease;  
    -moz-transition: height 2s ease;  
    -o-transition: height 2s ease;    
    transition: height 2s ease;  
    overflow:hidden;    
height:100px;

}


.closed {
    height:0px;
    overflow:hidden;

}
```